Displaying file content in a text box in jenkins pipeline
I have Created 2 pipelines in JENKINS

For starting automation on Virtual Machines - logs gets created from automation script in the VM
for generating the report out of the logs
I have written a python script that search for a keyword in these logs and create a csv report, where keyword is given in a separate file=> keyword.json.
The pipeline should display the file content from keyword.json so that user can edit this keyword before starting the GetReport pipeline, this will allow user to create csv report with different combination of keywords.

Tried input text - but displaying the file content is not working

So, you want the parameter to be editable in a textbox, but the default value to come from a file in a repo? No, Jenkins doesn't do that. For a fundamental reason - you specify parameters before any repo calls are made.
You could assign the default value to the parameter in the pipeline, but it would only affect the next run of the pipeline.
Another option would be to read the file once the pipeline is running and then use the input step to give user a chance to edit it. Doesn't make for a good user experience.
Would specifying the default value in the the parameter definition instead of a separate file work for you?
